# how to fix unexpected token at '' (JSON::ParserError)

Tags: json, vagrant

i used vagrant for a month and this happen yesterday when  i run "vagrant up" and my pc shuts down at that time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMHWN.jpg)

Comment: try a vagrant in it followed by vagrant up

Comment: i tried it shows same error

Answer (score 0):

The `.vagrant` file can get curropted sometimes. Try removing it and run `vagrant init`.
It should proceed without any error.

Comment: thank you, it worked but i lost my projects(files)

Comment: how come? deleting `.vagrant` should not cause any changes to source code

Comment: i mean my folders that i created...